# How to Use the HTML5/JS File Upload API to Upload a File to OData Service?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, odata

I have been searching all over the web and looking for a way to do this but I have not found even a single example.

I am trying to upload a file to an OData service using the HTML5 file upload API.

Currently I am receiving the following error:

> Invalid slug header for attachment. Slug headers must be of the form
>   "EntitySet,ItemId,Name".

I understand that the message is a bit misleading and the format should actually be

```
Slug: MyListTitle|1|mydocument.docx
```

I would be very grateful for any help on this topic!